# How to work with Date's intersect - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date

Let's suppose I have these records here in the table, any table for example.

```
09/07/2018 09/07/2018 08:30 09:37
09/07/2018 09/07/2018 08:30 09:38
09/07/2018 09/07/2018 08:30 09:40
09/07/2018 09/07/2018 08:30 09:42
09/07/2018 09/07/2018 08:30 09:43
09/07/2018 09/07/2018 08:30 09:45
```

Start Date - Final Date - Start Time - Final Time

And a user would like to enter a schedule type this

09/07/2018 09/07/2018 08:45 09:35

In fact, if the user types a start and end date with start and end time, I have to check for dates (records) that intersect with what he entered.

If you have more than 6 records there, do not enter the database if you have less than 6, you can insert.

Any ideas on this logic in MYSQL?

Comment: Asked and answered many times

Comment: i assuming MySQL should not be adding a record when a intersect exists besides when there are 6 records already?

Comment: For 6 records just check if the count of output is more/less and based on that (do not) allow action